# Sybase SQL not in & null

Tags: sql, sybase

A column BB has values null,1,2,3 and 4. I wrote SQL as below:

```
select BB
from table_s
where BB not in ('1','2')
```

But I only got result in '3' and '4', not including null. Is this Sybase SQL logic？（If so, I should use positive list for filter in the future. ）

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is standard SQL.  Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL` -- and in a `WHERE` clause it is treated as not-TRUE.

You need an explicit `or BB is null`.